# C++ struct with class as member, struct not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, class, struct

I declared a struct called ThreadParams and class Server and ThreadParams have member Server, inside class server there's a member function called dispatchThread (ThreadParams *params) that takes in a thread param. I'm not sure where to declare and use this struct, my server.cc and server.hh is below

```
class Server {
 public:

   struct ThreadParams {
      const Server * server;
      Socket_t sock;
   };

    void dispatchThread( ThreadParams * params);

};
```

below is where i used the method

```
#include "server.hh"

void dispatchThread( ThreadParams * params) {
  // do some stuff
}
```

however I got

```
error: ‘ThreadParams’ was not declared in this scope
error: ‘params’ was not declared in this scope
```

Any help is greatly appreciated !

Comment: `void Server::dispatchThread( ThreadParams * params) ` otherwise it is unrelated free function, not a class member function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the function signature "dispatchThread" like this

```
 void Server::ThreadParams::dispatchThread( ThreadParams * params) {
   // do some stuff
 }
```

Function dispatchThread should be visible from Server class.